# How to Add Gradle Support to Existing Github Repository?

Tags: android, github, gradle

I found this Github repository: https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView
and I want to include it in my Android App in AndroidStudio by adding just a single line to the repository to the build.gradle file, e.g.:

```
compile 'com.COMPANY.PROJECT:PROJECT:1.0.0'
```

Now, since the above mentioned HeaderListView project is lacking gradle support, I want to fork it and add gradle support. How can I achieve this? Can you please give me examples or point me to any tutorial or documentation about this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only import HeaderListView project,and add `include ':HeaderListView'` into settings.gradle, then add 
`dependencies {
    compile project(':HeaderListView')
}` into your main project's build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload it to Maven Central. Once it's live there, you can refer it as you asked

Comment: This tutorial describes the required steps: http://wiki.ivonet.nl/display/JAVA/Get+you+maven+project+into+the+Maven+Central+Repository